# Make requests with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, request

I started with AngularJS today and I trying send a post to my API with AngularJS but I don't get anything, not even a error 500 code when I click in my button.
What is the problem with my request?

API

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/veiculo")
public class VeiculoAPI {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/novo/{nome}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public void novoVeiculo(@Param("nome") String nome) {
        System.out.println("Veículo : " + nome);
    }

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="oknok">
<script>
    function salvar($scope) {
        var nomeVeiculo = $scope.veiculo;
        $http.post("/veiculo/novo/", {"veiculo" : "nomeVeiculo"})
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.data = data;
        }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.status = status;
        })
    }
</script>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>OKNOK Admin</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="formulario">

<center>
    <label>Veículo</label>
    <input type="text" ng-model="veiculo"/>
    <button ng-click="salvar()">Salvar</button>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see your code for your angular controller. Why not put the code there?

Comment: Where is controller: `formulario`? or you module delcaration for that matter

Comment: You need to setup your angular module first, and you have to inject the $http in your function. My advice is to learn a angular tutorial. [Angular Learning](https://github.com/jmcunningham/AngularJS-Learning)

Comment: you likely didn't add `salvar` to your controller's scope. or even create a controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make HTTP requests to any API with angularJS you need to do the following steps:

1. Create a Controller file & a controller within it
2. Create a angular module within the controller file
3. Create the HTTP request within the controller

**Create a controller.js file then create a angular module see code below:**

```
  //Within your controller.js file 
    var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
    myApp.controller('myController', function($scope, $http){

 // Create a function within the scope of the module
 $scope.makeRequest = function(){

    // Simple POST request example (passing data) :
    $http.post("API url here", {

         //Enter Request data in here, this is the data you want to pass to the API
         msg:"Hello World",
         name: "John Smith",
         gender: "Male"
    }).
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // this callback will be called asynchronously
        // when the response is available

    }).
    error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
    });
};
});
```

**Then within your HTML file call the function on-Click see code below:**

**Note:** Don't forget to add the controller you created into your HTML code. I usually add it in the body tag

```
 <body ng-controller="myController">
    <button ng-click="makeRequest()">Make Request Button</button>
 </body>
```

To make a GET Request see code below:

```
  // Simple GET request example :
  $http.get('/someUrl').
    success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  // this callback will be called asynchronously
 // when the response is available
 }).
   error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
   // or server returns response with an error status.
 });
```

I hope this helps.